# Not able to debug in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I came across this strange issue where I 'm not able to debug my application (Java Web Application) in Eclipse.

**History:**

1. I deleted and re-imported the same project again.
2. Debug was working before this.

**I tried:**

1. Refreshing my workspace (all the projects)
2. Did a Clean + Build.
3. Checked my debug configurations for valid port number inside eclipse.
4. Gave breakpoints on the obvious lines of code where I know the control will hit these points.

**Update**
I'm using JBoss server if that helps.

Any pointers which I might have missed out.?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JBoss Tools to start your appserver?

Comment: Sorry I didn't really get what exactly you are asking. I usually start my JBoss from .bat file.

Comment: What problem your are facing?Any errors, hanging....

Comment: No hang but my control doesn't stop in the breakpoints I specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've worked for years with Java web apps, using Eclipse and JBoss, and I've faced this issue multiple times.

What I'd usually do to fix this problem is erase `.metadata` folder from the workspace while Eclipse was closed (it will re-generate when opening again).

Comment: Can I delete the `.metadata` folder completely? Because I'm seeing lots of folders/files inside it.

Comment: @Java_User as far as I'm concerned, yes. Do a backup, so you can go back to previous state if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yup. Sure I'll do that then.

Comment: @Java_User I did the same still not helped me. But the problem in my eclipse is, it keeps on showing Connection refused. Have you faced this issue ever or do you have any idea reagarding this ?